# how C output LF to stdout without being changed to CR LF?

Tags: c, windows, line-endings, newline

On Windows this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    putc('A',stdout);
    putc('\r',stdout); 
    putc('\n',stdout);
}
```

outputs

```
A<CR><CR><LF>
```

How to write just LF char to stdout  without automatic conversion to CR LF?

I need it to make simple socket stream reader to stdout.
I've tried bcc32 from CodeGear, mingw, tinycc all yield same result, changing putc to putchar, fputc, fwrite doesn't help either.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The MSVC solution is:

```
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
...
_setmode(1,_O_BINARY)
```

Other runtimes may provide the C99 solution or an alternate way. EDIT: I believe `setmode([file number],O_BINARY)` originated on Borland Turbo C, and other compilers for MS-DOS and Windows imitated it. The _ prefix is done to keep the namespace clean, and may not be present on some compilers.

Comment: But it doesn't support passing `NULL` as the filename, and the stdout you start with doesn't necessarily _have_ a filename.

Comment: Thanks. It works, even without io.h included on tinycc and mingw. on bcc32 io.h must be included then change _setmode to setmode.

Comment: Starting with Windows 10 (at least) this is insufficient. The console does its own translation, which should be disabled separately by setting `DISABLE_NEWLINE_AUTO_RETURN` console mode. (The constant is defined in Windows 10 SDK, but not in Windows 8 SDK)

Comment: @AnT The OP does not mention the console. I assumed stdout was a pipe or file, because it's impossible to tell the difference between one CR and two in a row as in the example on the console.

Answer (score 3):

A text file converts the C character `'\n'` into the native line ending on output, and converts the native line ending on input into a single `'\n'`.

To get the result you require, you'd have to change `stdout` into a binary file stream.

A partial answer is found [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/213649-how-write-binary-data-stdout).  If you have a C99-compliant library, using:

```
if (freopen(0, "wb", stdout) == 0)
    ...oops...operation failed...
```

will attempt to change standard output to a binary stream.  However, on Windows, the 'C99-compliant library' might be a problem.  Nominally, this is the portable (because standard) answer.  There is likely a Windows-specific function to do the same job.

Comment: @Ignacio: yes, thanks - found that out...we live, we learn, we answer questions.

Comment: @James: The `freopen()` function has been in `<stdio.h>` since Version 7 Unix, but the behaviour with a null pointer for the file name is new in C99.  The C89 standard says nothing about a null pointer.

Answer (score 3):

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#endif

#ifdef __BORLANDC__
#define _setmode setmode
#endif

#include <stdio.h>

static void binary_stdout(void) {
#ifdef _WIN32
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_BINARY);
#endif
}

int main(void) {
    binary_stdout();
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```