# C++ - Read and print whole file

Tags: c++, unicode, printf, scanf

Like in the topic, I'd like to read from standard input and print to standard output whole file with no difference between them.

```
program < data.txt > data.out
diff data.txt data.out // <- the same
```

File contains Unicode letters.

I've managed write following piece of code:

```
char s[100000];

int main()
{
    setmode(1, _O_BINARY);

    char *n;

    do {
        n = gets(s);
        s[strlen(s)-1] = '\n';
        printf("%s", s);
    }
    while(n);

    return 0;
}
```

but input and output is slighty different (input: 76 465KB, output: 76 498KB)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Now, it's only 2KB difference.

**EDIT:**

It's OK.

Comment: My 2 cents : it's C, not C++ :)

Comment: I use printf, because is faster :)

Comment: Yes, and you use `char s[100000]` `setmode`, `char*`, `gets`, `strlen` too, which are not C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could happen if the input file has \n line endings. The output file will have \r\n line endings on Windows. That could explain the difference.

If you don't want to output the \rs, you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5813400/871910)

Comment: First make sure that is indeed the difference.