# Dart: print newline without carriage return on Windows?

Tags: dart, dart-io

I am trying to output text with *nix line endings from a windows dart vm, and it seems to be always replacing the \n with \r\n:

```dart
#!/usr/bin/env dart

# foo.dart

import 'dart:io';

main() {
  stdout.write('a\nb\nc\n');
  stdout.write('a\x0Ab\x0Ac\x0A');
}
```

Here's what I get when running from cygwin

```
$ foo.dart | foo.txt
$ cat -A foo.txt
a^M$
b^M$
c^M$
a^M$
b^M$
c^M$
```

Is there a way to output text without automatic carriage returns insertion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is that stdout is by default opened in text mode, in which Windows itself automatically converts LF to CRLF.

If it were C/C++ generally speaking you will be able to switch stdout to binary mode using _setmode(see [how C output LF to stdout without being changed to CR LF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813301/how-c-output-lf-to-stdout-without-being-changed-to-cr-lf)).

In Dart you don't have access to that API function.

I would raise a request for that on dartbug.com/new.