# fwrite to stdout - unknown extra bytes

Tags: c++, fwrite

When using fwrite to write to stdout I experience weird insertions.

I read from [original.txt](https://github.com/AiStudent/textfile/raw/master/original.txt) to a buffer, and then write the buffer both to file.txt and to stdout. I save the stdout to stdout.txt. All files are treated as binary files.

```
program.exe > stdout.txt
```

The file.txt becomes identical with original.txt.

stdout.txt has 3 extra bytes compared to original.txt, consisting of a inserted value 0x0D before every 0x0A.

What could be the reason for the insertions in stdout? Not sure I can trust stdout any more.

**Testing** is done in 2 steps:

```
program.exe > stdout.txt
```

Change true to false on line 16 and run:

```
program.exe
```

Expected output - occourances of insertions (offset,  inserted value, the original value):

```
6ec : d, a
c68 : d, a
ecc : d, a
```

**Code:**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    // original.txt -> read_data
    char read_data[0x1000];
    FILE * original_p = fopen("original.txt", "rb");
    fread(read_data, 1, 0x1000, original_p);        
    fclose(original_p);

    //True  : write files.
    //False : compare files.
    if (true) 
    {
        // read_data -> file.txt
        FILE * file_p = fopen("file.txt", "wb");
        fwrite(&read_data[0], 1, 0x1000, file_p);
        fclose(file_p);

        // read_data -> stdout
        fwrite(&read_data[0], 1, 0x1000, stdout);
    }
    else
    {
        // stdout.txt -> stdout_data
        char stdout_data[0x1003];
        FILE * stdout_file = fopen("stdout.txt", "rb");
        fread(stdout_data, 1, 0x1003, stdout_file);
        fclose(stdout_file);

        // Compares read_data and stdout_data:
        int extra_offset = 0;   // Compensates for insertions in stdout_data.
        for (int n = 0; n < 0x1000;n++)
        {
            if (stdout_data[n + extra_offset] != read_data[n])
            {
                // Prints offset : stdout_data[n + extra_offset], read_data[n] 
                std::cout << std::hex <<
                    n << " : " <<  
                    (((unsigned int) stdout_data[n + extra_offset]) & 0xFF) << ", " <<
                    (((unsigned int) read_data[n]) & 0xFF) << "\n";

                extra_offset += 1;
            }
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your OS is helping you by adding a `\r` to each of your `\n` characters.  DOS/Windows likes `\r\n` for its text file line endings.

Comment: That would be because `stdout` is in text mode by default.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813301/how-c-output-lf-to-stdout-without-being-changed-to-cr-lf