# NodeJS: Send EOF to stdin stream without closing stream

Tags: javascript, node.js

**How can I signal EOF to a stream without closing the stream?**

I've got a script that waits for input on stdin, then when I push ctrl-d, it spits output to stdout, then waits again for stdin until I press ctrl-d.

In my nodejs script, I want to spawn that script, write to the stdin stream, then somehow signal EOF without closing the stream. This doesn't work:

```
var http = require('http'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var child = spawn('my_child_process');
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});

child.stdout.on('close', function() {
    console.log('closed');
})

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    child.stdin.write('hello child\n');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

But if I change child.stdin.write(...) to child.stdin.end(...), it works, but only once; the stream is closed after that. I read somewhere that EOF isn't actually a character, it's just anything that's NOT a character, usually -1, so I tried this, but this didn't work either:

```
var EOF = new Buffer(1); EOF[0] = -1;
child.stdin.write("hello child\n");
child.stdin.write(EOF);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633577/send-a-eof-in-a-pipe-without-closing-it

Comment: Why can't you just close the input stream? I'm rather confused here.

Comment: Because I want to write again to stdin. The process waits for EOF, then chunks on the input, then reopens /dev/stdin to wait for more.

Comment: That seems horribly against the concept of unix, who wrote the other process?

Comment: I wrote it. It's a PhantomJS script. Looks like I may have to rework that. It's not unprecedented though; coders in Python, C, C++, and probably others have wondered the same thing.

Comment: You can change the EOL character for the life of your program to help you test: http://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_eol

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried `child.stdin.write("\x04");`? This is the ascii code for Ctrl+D.

Comment: Is this cross-platform? Would that work on Windows also?

Comment: I'm not sure. The question and answer predate node.js support on Windows; I have never run node.js in a Windows environment. Is `Ctrl+D` a signal in Windows?

Answer (score 3):

You did it with `res` just two lines below...

> - `stream.write(data)` is used when you, want to continue writing
> - `stream.end([data])` is used when you don't need to send more data (it will close the stream)

```
var http = require('http'),
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var child = spawn('my_child_process');
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data.toString());
});

child.stdout.on('close', function() {
    console.log('closed');
})

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    child.stdin.end('hello child\n');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var os = require("os");    
child.stdin.write("hello child\n");
child.stdin.write(os.EOL);
```

I use this in my project and it works

Comment: EOF != EOL. EOL is probably \r\n on Windows and \n on Linux.

Comment: @joonas.fi yupp