# When does this program return 0

Tags: c, arrays, string

The following function is to return the length of a line that is entered through keyboard. But its saying that (The C Programming language K & R) `it will return the length of the line, or zero if end of file is encountered.` But when I analyzed with my basic knowledge in C at least it is returning the length of the line till `EOF`. So when does it returns `0`. Or my understanding is wrong. Can anybody clarify me ?

```
int getline(char s[],int lim)
{
    int c, i;
    for (i=0; i < lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!=’\n’; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == ’\n’) {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = ’\0’;
    return i;
}
```

Comment: if the string is empty.it returns 0

Comment: I think your analysis is correct. It will return the number of chars read until EOF or newline.

Comment: @harald but it actually returns 0 when `EOF` is encountered

Comment: @noufal, only if the file is empty or the last charecter in the file is a newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When there's nothing, EOF will be there e.g. in case of **Empty line**, `c==EOF` and you have entered a condition in your `for` loop that `(c=getchar())!=EOF`. Thus `i` won't change and when it will be returned after execution of `return i;`, it will return `0`

I hope this helps.

Comment: suppose if I am entering like `qwertyEOF`, it should return the number `6` ? right ?

Comment: No. it will return 9. Read this for explanation of EOF in detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061135/can-we-write-an-eof-character-ourselves 

p.s please Vote UP for answer and accept it. it encourages infact ;)

Comment: CTRL + D ? As per my knowledge, EOF by definition "is unequal to any valid character code" and there's no such character. in DOS, it used to be CTRL + Z but not now.

Comment: Entering EOF at end of line won't make it read EOF infact, it will treat it as normal characters.

Comment: I did understand your point. BTW I didn't mean entering `E, O, F` from keyboard.

Comment: Accept answer Please then.

Answer (score 2):

You analyzed the program correctly.

> But when I analyzed with my basic knowledge in C at least it is **returning the length of the line** till EOF

-> It will return 0 when the line is empty

Comment: ... but isn't it just returning the length of the line, then? Why mentioning this case as something special?

Comment: It returns the length of the line, yes, as seen in the quote.

Comment: Together with noufal, I'm wondering why the quote doesn't just say "it will return the length of the line". Or, why not "... or 1 if there is an EOF after one character in a line"?

Comment: @undur_gongor Because then it wouldn't be a quote anymore

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt if `EOF` is at the end a line, it should return the number of characters in that line ?

Answer (score 0):

If the line is empty, it will return 0.

```
for (i=0; i < lim-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!=’\n’; ++i)
```

First, You set `i=0;`. If `((c=getchar())==EOF)`, the for loop won't run and `i` won't be incremented. The situation is the same when the first character is a `\n` (in this case i will be incremented later)

Comment: when  the first character is `\n`, it will return `1`, not `0`

Comment: @noufal Yes, You're right. i will be incremented later outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

one of the conditions in the `for` loop is `(c=getchar())!=EOF`. So when the line is empty, ie. `c==EOF` at the first instance itself, it doesnt enter the loop. Hence `i` won't get incremented and it returns 0.

Comment: if I enter the `EOF` at the end of a line, then ?

Comment: @noufal can you explain a bit?

Comment: I got now what was wrong with my understanding. If nothing is there, `EOF` will be there over and over again